# Allow certain IP ranges and googlebot, deny the rest, for certain URLs only

Tags: .htaccess, geolocation, googlebot

I need to modify and combine some .htaccess rules, in order  to meet 3 separate conditions:

- Allow access from certain IP ranges, deny the rest
- Allow googlebot, no matter what IP
- All this applies only to any URL containing 'theword'

> ```
> <Directory "containing *theword*">
>    Order allow,deny
>    Deny from all
>    Allow from 192.168.0.2
>    Allow from 10.0.0.1
> </Directory>
> <Files "containing *theword*">
>    Order allow,deny
>    Deny from all
>    Allow from 192.168.0.2
>    Allow from 10.0.0.1
> </Files>
> ```

I need help formatting rule with the files/directories containing theword and add exception for the googlebot.

Comment: What version of Apache are you on? You mention IP “ranges” - what kind of “ranges”? Your example only references specific IPs. What other directives do you have in your .htaccess file? Do you have any other (unrelated) rules that might block Googlebot?

Comment: @MrWhite
v.2.4.41. The ranges I got from https://www.countryipblocks.net/acl.php
There are 400 lines of other directives (Prestashop standard htaccess file), I can post it if necessary. No directives related to googlebot.

Comment: @MrWhite Are you able to help me?